# Android MPEG DASH Client

Tags: android, mpeg, mpeg-dash

I'm trying to implement an MPEG-DASH client on android , I'm trying to use the libdash library through NDK but the problem that it doesn't have any documentations or tutorial that really helps.

Can someone give me a good tutorial plz

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at the documentation: http://www.bitmovin.net/files/bitmovin/content/documentation/libdash/3_0/index.html

You may also contact the developers via: https://github.com/bitmovin/libdash